# Do I use .env or .env.local for local development?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

If I develop locally on my computer a VueJS App. Is `.env` the file in which I store the accesses for locally or `.env.local`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.env`, don't overcomplicate things.
There are also `.env.production`, `.env.development` etc...but those are not recommended either.

As explained here: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files

Comment: thank you for the link. But I see it completely differently. Especially when you build a SPA and use certain settings / configurations from the env to build a bundle for the respective stage, it makes sense to have the different enviroments locally. Especially because you don't want to play them on the server.

Comment: @MaxPattern for those situations, you push your code and the CI will make that for you. Hence, having local env variables for your dev journey while having staging/test/pre-prod/prod variables remotely. Your app should be deployed on a preview environment anyway and may have bigger connections to some backend or some dynamic things moving around setup by a devops team. If you're working alone on a small project, then you will have other env variables on Netlify/Vercel anyway too. Don't mix and match those, can be risky and error-prone.

Comment: I'm just realising. I build locally with vitejs the bundle for staging or production and push the static data via scp to the server. But it only ever uses the .env.local. :-(

Comment: @MaxPattern move out from SCP to Git, you will have an easier time and less issues. Also, feel free to delete `.env.local`.