# .env.production variable undefined after Vue build

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, npm-build

I have two `.env` files in my Vue 2.2.3 project, `.env.development` and `.env.production`.

In each `.env` file I have assigned `VUE_APP_API_URL` variable to different values - one for my local development environment and the other the production server.

Running `npm run build` compiles the app into the `dist` folder locally without any issues. However, when I deploy the `dist` to my server logging the `VUE_APP_API_URL` inside my Vue app comes back `undefined`.

This is the first time I have done this so I may be missing something. Is there something else I must do to have the `.env.production` URL to work with the build?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I recommend using this approach (question asked earlier today): https://stackoverflow.com/a/74059267/8816585

Comment: can you please share on the package.json the string behind the scripts.build?

Comment: How **exactly** are you logging the `VUE_APP_API_URL` variable? Show the code!

Comment: @MichalLevý To know if you failed to something do that. In your IDE (vscode can) search for all occurence `VUE_APP_API_URL`, if you see it inside some file in dist\js it say the variable is available. (I do not talk about the occurence when you call it, you need to see the variable and value for example `NODE_ENV:"production",VUE_APP_API_URL:"https://my-url.com"`)

Comment: @MichalLevý There's not much to it but here it is`console.log('ENV URL -> ', process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL)`

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is: Do not overcomplicate. Just use one single .env file.

Just make sure to don't push it to the repo, otherwise it would be public. That's all.

I my config I've got: .env for dev with the constants in there.

Then In the production enviroment you just set the Variables there.

Answer (score 0):

You should not push `.env.production` to git repo but if you really want to do it, on build command you can do like this on `package.json` file

```
"build": "cp .env.production .env && vue-cli-service build",
```

Comment: If gitignored, this will still not work haha.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what pushing `.env` to git will do to solve the issue. For the record, I never push `.env` files to git as that defeats the purpose.